# Unknown 8pin smd component marking 2050

Tags: identification, surface-mount

This is a component off my fisher & paykel dishwasher controller.

Based on how the circuit it is in, operates:

When pin 1 is hi, pin 4 will connect with pin 2&3 which connect to GND. Pin 4 is the low end from a small fan. Pin1 is from an MCU pin similarly with pin 8 & 5...pin 5 connects to 6&7 when 8 is hi.

Also, how would one even describe it so as to look up parts suppliers websites?

Thanks in advance
moshe[image]

Comment: why do you need a replacenent?

Comment: Judging from the picture and your description, it’s probably two N-channel MOSFETs in a single package. One of them has failed with a short between gate and drain

Comment: to answer jsotola...reason for the replacement is that this one failed & the cause of the failure was the fan going short circuit which caused this to have to deal with too high a current flow...and its cheaper to replace the IC than the controller.

Comment: @jsotola Why is it relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's a dual N-channel enhancement mode MOSFET. Specifically, [HAT2050T by Renesans](https://www.renesas.com/document/dst/hat2050t-datasheet?language=en&r=1340446): Vdss 100 V, Id 1 A, RDSon 0,56 Ω. That package is TSSOP-8.

[image]

Comment: yes...it fits the pinouts...great...i will check its datasheet & if not the right specs i will search for another n-channel dual mosfet.
THANK YOU

Comment: @moshejay please accept this answer then (by clicking the tick button) so that the question does not remain open.